# How to add interstitial google ads on my libGDX application?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am a beginner programmer. I developed a game using libGDX and I have versions for android and desktop. I would like to add Google ads on my android part of the game, but unfortunately I do not know how to do that. I tried to follow their official tutorial and some over tutorials I found, but without any success. I do not know android development. I know only libGDX. I created the game by extending the Game class and implementing the Screen interface. I would like to know how to implement an interstitial ad between two Screens chosen by me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should check this tutorial - https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx , it's very well explained.